# ocaml list to array array

Tags: list, ocaml

I'm trying to convert a list with a specified width to array array.
For example, i want to convert this :

```
int list = [97; 114; 110; 97; 117; 100; 2]
```

to

```
int array array = [| [|97; 114; 110|]; [|97; 117; 100|]; [|2; 0; 0|] |]
```

I am not used to ocaml so I tried to use this code :

```
let split list width =
  let rec aux i acc = function
    | [] -> List.rev acc, []
    | h :: t as l -> 
      if i = 0 
      then List.rev acc, l
      else aux (i-1) (h :: acc) t  in
aux width [] list;;
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code? Please be specific and see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code in a language you have to get used to it :) You have to spend a couple of hours and read at least the [intoduction](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/coreexamples.html) to OCaml. The first chapter would be enough to be able to solve your example.

In your particular example, (which I took the liberty to reindent, to make it more readable), the variable `n` in `aux n [] list` is unbound. Indeed, what `n` is supposed to mean? Another tip, is that the `width` parameter of your function is not used in the body of your function. You probably already get it... but do not rush to fix it. First, read the introductory course to OCaml :)

Answer (score 0):

I would work backwards on this problem.

First I would create a function which takes a list, a padding value and the number of times that padding must be applied. Something like this:

```
val add_padding: int -> int -> int list -> int list
```

Next I would create a function which takes a list and a width and returns a new list and the remainder of the list passed in... This should fail if the passed in list is too short. Something like:

```
val create_new_list: int -> 'a list -> 'a list * 'a list
```

With these two functions, you should be able to split your input list.

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with mutable types like arrays that lend themselves to imperative solutions, there's no shame in using the best tool for the job.

```
let split lst width =
  let arr = Array.of_list lst in
  let len = Array.length arr in
  let height = 
    int_of_float 
    @@ ceil 
    @@ float_of_int len /. float_of_int width   
  in 
  let result = Array.make_matrix height width 0 in
  for i = 0 to len - 1 do
    result.(i / width).(i mod width) <- arr.(i)
  done;
  result
```

```
# split [97; 114; 110; 97; 117; 100; 2] 3;;
- : int array array = [|[|97; 114; 110|]; [|97; 117; 100|]; [|2; 0; 0|]|]
```